# List of values as input for keyword/value notation input => in Oracle

Tags: oracle

There was this piece of query in my code:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX (DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5 ( input_string => 'a_text')) FROM dual;
```

The value 'a_text' is hard coded for the input string. 
What if I need this text to be taken from a table that contains a list of text fields?

I tried the same with:

```
SELECT Rawtohex (dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.Md5 (input_string in (SELECT textValue FROM table WHERE table_id = id)))  AS HEX FROM   dual;
```

Obviously throws:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Hope the solution would help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select directly from the table, not from `dual`:

```
SELECT Rawtohex (dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.Md5 (input_string => t.textValue)) AS HEX
FROM your_table t
WHERE t.table_id = some_id;
```

The fact that your version got ORA-01427 suggests you will get multiple values back because `table_id` is not unique. Well, except your code actually throws "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"; but if you had `=>` instead of `in` it could get ORA-01427...

Quick demo with sample data in a CTE:

```
with your_table (table_id, textvalue) as (
  select 42, 'a_text'  from dual
  union all select 42, 'b_text' from dual
  union all select 43, 'c_text' from dual
)
SELECT Rawtohex (dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.Md5 (input_string => t.textValue)) AS HEX
FROM your_table t
WHERE t.table_id = 42;

HEX                             
--------------------------------
55EA1381DBC9F3CE146B55CC75B28147
CFD9FD9A2BA3FDD917E8CAB4EF644838
```

Comment: Great you are !